# Create array with Unique combinations for json Input

Tags: java

I am trying to create an array and trying to find all the matches entries/values. I suppose I need a recursive function for this.

I like to get all values from the JSON below and create an array with all value combinations. There may be more or fewer values. Any help?

```
 {  
 "user":{  
  "vals":["SFO","ORD","GFO","LHT","SFO"],
  "col_no":0
},
"email":{  
  "vals":["DFW","OR","IAX","LHT","CDG"],
  "col_no":1
}
}
```

And the output I'm trying to achieve.
  output:    `

```
     ["SFO","DFW"],
       ["SFO","OR"],
       ["SFO","IAX"],
       ["SFO","LHT"],
       ["SFO","CDG"],
        ["ORD","DFW"].......`
```

suggest me some ideas to crack this output

Comment: this site does not provide source codes, it helps you if you faced a problem in a source code, so what have you tried so far? what is not working as you expect? **hint** use a nested for loops add key-values to a collection / array/ list. ..., before adding key-value check if they are already exist?!

Comment: Thanks buddy. I'll use nested loop